# Anonymous window Too many SOQL queries: 101

Tags: update, governorlimits, execute-anonymous

I've tried to execute the following script:

```
List<Task> taskList = [SELECT status, CalculatedWorkingHours__c FROM Task WHERE CalculatedWorkingHours__c = -1.0 AND status = 'Completed'];
        for(Task task :taskList) {
            task.CalculatedWorkingHours__c = 1.0;
        }   
        update taskList;
        System.debug('taskList ' + taskList);
```

in Anonymous window in my Developer Console however I received the following message: `System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101`

Please advise how to avoid such exception and execute my script successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing *clearly* wrong with this anonymous script as such. However, it's invoking any `update` triggers you have in place on Task, along with any declarative automations like Workflow Rules and Processes, and it may be doing so with a large list of Tasks.

Cumulatively, all the code that's run when you perform the update is using more than 100 SOQL queries, including the one you run in this script. The most likely reason for this, if your initial query doesn't return a huge number of Tasks, is that your trigger is running SOQL in a loop, which would need to be bulkified.

If there's a large number of Tasks in that list, it may also be the case that your triggers are moderately but not catastrophically inefficient in their use of SOQL and aren't tuned to handle more than 200 records in a transaction.

Your best route around this issue without code changes would be to export the Tasks and make your changes in Excel or LibreOffice, then update them via Data Loader and set your batch size to something less than 200, reducing the batch size until the error goes away.